# How to use String.Replace String Using Regexp in Robot Framework to add colon after every 2 characters

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

I am new to Robot Framework, and I am using to run some automation.

I have a string that looks like this:

> A1S2D3F4G5H6J7K8L9

I need to add colon after every 2 characters to make it look like this

> A1:S2:D3:F4:G5:H6:J7:K8:L9

I wrote this line of code using the 'String.Replace String Using Regexp 'but it gives me the wrong output:

```
${test_value}    String.Replace String Using Regexp    ${test_value}    /(..)/g, '$1:    :
BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${test_value}
```

Can someone please help me out? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the pattern to be replaced as `(..)` and replace with pattern as `\\1:`. To avoid getting a `:` in the end, set the pattern to `(..)(?=[^$])`

```
> ${test_value}    String.Replace String Using Regexp    ${test_value}    (..)(?=[^$])    \\1:                                                                                                                                                 
# ${test_value} = 'A1:S2:D3:F4:G5:H6:J7:K8:L9'
> BuiltIn.Log To Console    ${test_value}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
A1:S2:D3:F4:G5:H6:J7:K8:L9
>
```